# Реализация корзины в Telegram bot Python (aiogram)

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

[image: Схема того, как должна работать корзина]
Подскажите, как и с помощью чего можно реализовать корзину на Aiogram'e?Знаю,что 100% нужна база данных( в боте используется sqlite3) , но я не могу придумать как это всё написать.

Comment: Вы идете в верном направление, попробуйте полностью прописать все команды Вашего бота, и продумать функционал, затем уже продумайте структуру БД. А после в запросах, Вы просто как-то взаимодействуете с БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать примерно так:

Есть список товаров (скажем, в переменной)

```
    items={'tort1':{'name':'Торт первой модели', 'price':10}}
```

Есть база данных - 'корзина'

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `korzina` (
        `user_id` VARCHAR(99999) NULL,
        `item` TEXT DEFAULT NULL)
```

Человек добавляет предмет в корзину:

```
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `korzina` (?,?)', (user_id, item))
    cursor.commit()
```

Как удаляем из корзины:

```
    cursor.execute('DELETE FROM `korzina` WHERE `user_id`=?', (user_id,))
    cursor.commit()
```

Берем список предметов:

```
    SELECT * FROM `korzina` WHERE `user_id` = ...
```

Все! Мы получили список предметов!
Список будет в формате: `((1234, 'tort1'), (1234, 'tort2'))`
Второе значение - название товара из списка товаров ранее - по нему можем из списка достать всю информацию. Если что-то непонятно - пиши - буду рад помочь)
P.S. Тут все под sqlite3

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! А как реализовать кнопку отмены(возвращения обратно) не знаете?

Comment: Полная отмена (удаление всей корзины) показана у меня в примере 'как удаляем из корзины'. Удаление же одного предмета можно реализовать через And (where user_id =? and item =?) (просто дописать and item =? к примеру выше). P. S. Если решил вопрос - буду рад если примете мой ответ за решение задачи)

Comment: Вроде-бы принял, ссорян, я новенький. Отмена я имел ввиду кнопку перемещения по меню. К примеру пользователь жмëт /start  и ему выдаëтся 3 кнопки (с тортами, пирожными и конфетами). Пользователь нажимает на конфеты и я хотел бы реализовать кнопку отмены, которая бы вернула его к начальному меню.

Comment: Тупанул,это кнопка не "отмена" - а "Назад"

Comment: По идее можно добавить callback-кнопку и handler который будет выполнять ту же фк-цию как и /start - выдавать главное меню